# How to upgrade unmanaged Cloudera CDH cluster to 6.1?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am not able to locate any docs to upgrade unmanaged cluster (running 5.16) via command line like the one below for 5.15

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/cdh_ig_upgrade_command_line.html

Can someone point me to the corresponding doc for 6.1 ?

Comment: You probably have to ask on the Cloudera Forums. 
 https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/bd-p/CDHInstall

Comment: Yes already asked there . But did not get any reply so posted here also. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/Upgrade-unmanaged-CDH-Cluster-to-6-1-from-5-16/td-p/85703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in [cloudera forum](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Upgrade-unmanaged-CDH-Cluster-to-6-1-from-5-16/m-p/287220/highlight/true#M212923). Cross-posting to prevent link rot

> 1. You can upgrade the packages based cluster but it's very tedious
>      process so not recommended.
>      https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/upgrade/topics/ug_overview.html
> 2. The best way is to migrate from packages to parcels and then
>      upgrade.
>      https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/latest/topics/cm_ig_migrating_packages_to_parce...
> 3. Once you migrated you can use this page to get the CM server running
>      with Web UI.
>      https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/installation.html
>      Regarding your ask "Is there any way by which an Unmanaged 5.x
>      cluster can move to CDH 6.x (may be adding it in Cloudera Manager
>      and then moving to 6.x)?"
>
> I am thinking that you can build a 1 node CM server and then add these
>   present cluster by adding node in that CM. (Though I haven't tried
>   this on packages)